# Tensorflow:: How to get layers with trainable parameters

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I'm using pretrained Xception model from TensorFlow.

```
base_model = keras.applications.Xception(
    weights='imagenet',
    input_shape=(150,150,3),
    include_top=False
)
```

It shows like 132 layers:

```
len(base_model.layers)
```

But only part of them have trainable parameters (This 132 includes Activation layers, MaxPool, and other e.g concatenating). So thers my question: **Is there a way to access only those layers with trainable parameters (should be like 71 of them)?**

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
for layer in base_model.layers:
    if layer.trainable:
        print (layer.name)
```

Comment: I mean, this should work, but it not suits me. I'm doing fine-tuning, and some times I will do ```base_model.trainable=False```. So I would like to hava access to all layers with trainable parameters regardless whether they are currently trainable true or false

Comment: I actually chcecked, and no - your loop still shows 132 layers

Comment: So I guess the layer.trainable attribute is assigned as   True even if the layer has no trainable parameters which is unfortunate

Answer (score 1):

I have found answer by myself. Its not perfect, but closest to what I wanted.

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.layer_utils import count_params

for layer in base_model.layers:
  if layer.count_params() > 0:
    print(layer.name)
```

It shows 80 layers, and batch_normalization amongs them - dunno why, I thought they dont have trainable parameters.